# facebook query pages sort on likes

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-fql

I am looking for a way to query facebook pages that for example, have something to do with food.

Not to difficult ;)

```
$pages = $facebook->api('search?q=food&type=page');
```

But... I want to get the largest pages (most likes) of that category. Search get's close, but I can't influence the return order (I think).

I have been looking here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/
to see if I can get it to work with a query, but it seems I can only query information about a specific page.

I have been looking for several solutions without succes. Is this even possible at all? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Make that request to "[search?q=food&type=page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dfood%26type%3Dpage)", then take the results and iterate over them.

For each result make the following FQL query:

```
SELECT 
    name, username, fan_count 
FROM 
    page 
WHERE 
    page_id="ITERATION_PAGE_ID"
```

For example, the first result I get has the id "25255939006", the FQL will be:

> [SELECT name, username, fan_count FROM page WHERE
>   page_id="25255939006"](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20name,%20username,%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=%2225255939006%22)

And the result is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Food", 
      "username": "", 
      "fan_count": 146291
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that. But I wonder: The search result seems random, or at least not taking the amount of likes into it's return criteria. That probably means I can get the biggest page of the  search result, but not of all pages in that category.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying/asking

Comment: Let me try to clarify :). The result that comes from "search?q=food&type=page" returns 25 results. But it doesn't necessarily return the pages with the largest fan count. Can I get it to return the pages with the largest fan count at all times?

Comment: If you click the first link in my answer, and scroll down in the results panel, you'll see the link for the "next" results page. You can follow that to the end of the results and then find out which is the "biggest". There's no way, that I'm aware of, to "order" the results by the fan amount.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you. That should work, I am not sure if this is going to be a good solution for the purpose I am after, but thank you very much for this answer!